# Is it possible to use an if statement in SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So basically I have a database that holds queued up emails for an email campaign.

The emails can have a bunch of different statuses and if the emails fail, they are reattempted.

The table looks like

```
id       email              status      attempts

0       test@test.com       failed         4

0       test@test.com       success        2

0       test@test.com       success        1

0       test@test.com       failed         2

0       test@test.com       new            0
```

I want to get a count of all of the emails that have sent so far or have too many attempts.

In other words count all of the emails where status != 'new', but if status = 'failed' only count the ones with an attempt of 4 or higher.

Is this possible with an SQL query, or do I have to do this in PHP?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't figure out how to make it look readable.

Comment: you can highlight and hit ctrl-k (format code) or indent 4 spaces

Comment: Instead of If statements you can use CASE statements

Comment: you may do it combining SUM and IF MySQL syntax, check for my answer, XD

Comment: You do realise that the entire point of SQL is to query data like this, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

You may add a where condition, and sum all the results you need:

```
SELECT 
  SUM( IF( STATUS = 'failed' AND attempts >= 4, 1, 0 ) ) AS total_failed 
, SUM( 1 ) AS total_olds
FROM my_table
WHERE STATUS != 'new'
```

The sum only will add the value 1 if you match the IF condition. In MySQL, if the IF clause matches, applies the first part, else the second (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html) Here, we say "hey, if the condition is matched, sum 1 row, else, do nothing", and this way you get all the results in one row, XD.

And as we're only selecting not 'new' rows, only adding 1 (SUM(1)) we'll get the value of all the rows matched.

Comment: Not all DBs allow `IF` in this was. SQL only requires `CASE`.

Comment: Thanks! This worked! I had no idea how IFs worked in SQL and now I know, thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

You could write

```
WHERE status = 'success'
   OR status = 'failed' AND attempts >= 4
```

Comment: WHERE status = 'success'
   OR (status = 'failed' AND attempts >= 4)

Comment: You're mixing and and or statements.  You need parenthesis somewhere.

Comment: @nbirla: `AND` has higher precedence than `OR`. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/operator-precedence.html.

Comment: @Robbert: No, I don't. `AND` has higher precedence than `OR`. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/operator-precedence.html. (This is standard across a wide range of programming languages, not to mention the fundamentals of computer science and Boolean logic.) Also, `AND` and `OR` are not "statements", they're *operators*.

Answer (score 0):

```
   add a where clause to your select as:
    where status ="success" or status = "failed" and attempts >= 4
```

no need to add `status !='new'` if you don't want to select on this criteria.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your query using sum with expression,in Mysql it is evaluated as boolean,So first sum with expression will give you the count for email where status is not equal to failed and sum with expression will give you the count where status is failed and attempts are more than 3 and then add up the results of both expression will give you the desired count

```
select email
sum(status <> 'failed') + sum(status = 'failed' and attempts > 3)  as your_count
from table   
where status <> 'new'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query below:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(email)


FROM 'your table'

WHERE 
STATUS = 'success'
OR 
(STATUS = 'failed' AND attempts >=4)
```

Comment: `STATUS = 'success' AND` should be `STATUS = 'success' OR`. No row will have a `status` of both 'success' and 'failed'

Comment: with that you only count, and you can't make two different counts as the select retrieves all the values filtered. With SUM and IF, you can, with the same selected results, make two or more counting, check my answer